# TemplateBuilder and SideWaffle. Project template. Change default root namespace

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2013, sidewaffle

I have successfully created a multiproject template using this guide:
https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki/How-to-create-a-multi-project-template

The issue im having is the ability to change the default namespace and default assembly name for the generated projects.
Like it is explained here: 
http://reasoncodeexample.com/2013/06/09/creating-visual-studio-project-templates/
where a **custom parameter** defines f.ex. the default namespace.

Essentially i would like to ensure that our company name is always in the beginning of the namespace...

I cannot make it work with the SideWaffle project template, and im wondering if anyone has an idea as to how one can define the default namespace and assemblyname, while using the SideWaffle project template.

Comment: can somebody help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684282/how-to-replace-name-of-solutions-an-namespace-in-multi-project-template-of-visua

Comment: can somebody help me with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684282/how-to-replace-name-of-solutions-an-namespace-in-multi-project-template-of-visua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tracked down what goes on. Since it will be a lengthy post i will make a new answer that explains the problems @ThBlitz

This is not an answer, but a further explanation into the above issues, and i apologize for the length.

So i have setup a IWizard implementation to modify the csproj and as discussed with @Sayed i have tried his solution.
Here are my findings.

This is the interresting part of the `IWizard` implementation

```
public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
        {
            replacementsDictionary.Add("$companynamespace$", "Infomedia");
        }
```

And the `_preprocess.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Preprocess>
  <TemplateInfo Path="CSharp\Infomedia"/>
  <Replacements Include="*.*" Exclude="*.vstemplate;*.csproj;*.jpg;*.png;*.ico;_preprocess.xml;_project.vstemplate.xml">
    <add key="ConsoleApp" value="$safeprojectname$"/>
    <add key="RootNamespace" value="$companynamespace$.$safeprojectname$"/>
    <add key="AssemblyName" value="$companynamespace$.$safeprojectname$"/>
    <add key="namespace" value="namespace $companynamespace$.$safeprojectname$"/>
  </Replacements>
</Preprocess>
```

The namespace part is only to **test** that the wizard is executed, and indeed it is, because i can observe that change to namespacing in all classes in the template in the experimental VS. (the classes are then invalid, but at least it shows the execution of the wizard).

But it should change the `RootNamespace` and `Assemblyname` and to do that i will need to remove the exclusion of `*.csproj` in the `_preprocess.xml`

Doing this change invalidates the xml.
Example of cleaned `_preprocess.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Preprocess>
  <TemplateInfo Path="CSharp\Infomedia"/>
  <Replacements Include="*.*" Exclude="*.vstemplate;*.jpg;*.png;*.ico;_preprocess.xml;_project.vstemplate.xml">
    <add key="ConsoleApp" value="$safeprojectname$"/>
    <add key="RootNamespace" value="$companynamespace$.$safeprojectname$"/>
    <add key="AssemblyName" value="$companynamespace$.$safeprojectname$"/>
    <add key="namespace" value="namespace $companynamespace$.$safeprojectname$"/>
  </Replacements>
</Preprocess>
```

observe the removal of `*.csproj`

Building the solution will cause compile error:

```
Name cannot begin with the '$' character, hexadecimal value 0x24. Line 10, position 6.
```

Ok. so the problem is now the presense of `$` and removing them and any whitespaces will allow the solution to build, but of course the replacement will not work, since the replacement values cannot be found.

Modified xml that builds but does not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Preprocess>
  <TemplateInfo Path="CSharp\Infomedia"/>
  <Replacements Include="*.*" Exclude="*.vstemplate;*.jpg;*.png;*.ico;_preprocess.xml;_project.vstemplate.xml">
    <add key="ConsoleApp" value="$safeprojectname$"/>
    <add key="RootNamespace" value="companynamespace.safeprojectname"/>
    <add key="AssemblyName" value="companynamespace.safeprojectname"/>
    <add key="namespace" value="companynamespace.safeprojectname"/>
  </Replacements>
</Preprocess>
```

So @Sayed i really hope you have an idea as to what is going on here.

Comment: U should disable building the source project in VS configuration manager. See video at https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki/How-to-create-your-own-template-pack. If that doesn't work can you email me the sample project or post it on github? My email is sayedha@microsoft.com

Comment: Project building is disabled for all configs.
I have posted the solution at github.
master builds but does not process the csproj: https://github.com/LogikBlitz/ConsoleTemplateTest/tree/master

feature has a modified preprocess but does not build:
https://github.com/LogikBlitz/ConsoleTemplateTest/tree/feature_removeCsprojFromPreprocess

@Sayed thanks for your help, and patience, so far :-)

Comment: Problem solved: https://github.com/LogikBlitz/ConsoleTemplateTest/issues/1#issuecomment-67303045
Essentially the problem was that my custom replacement invalidated the ``csproj`` file and thus the template validate would fail on build. I did not recognise that the csproj is actually transformed on build. Solution here was to use the following replacement part of ``_preprocess.xml``.

``
<Replacements Include="*.*" Exclude="*.vstemplate;*.jpg;*.png;*.ico;_preprocess.xml;_project.vstemplate.xml">
    <add key="ConsoleApp" value="NamespacePrefix.$safeprojectname$"/>
  </Replacements>
``

Comment: You should mark this as the answer so it doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

When using [SideWaffle](http://sidewaffle.com) (to be more specific, [TemplateBuilder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TemplateBuilder/), which SideWaffle is built on top of) you should be able to achieve this if you are creating a custom wizard.

I would recommend getting a sample project template with a custom wizard wired up first. Once you know your wizard is being invoked then start moving on.

Try the following

1. Make your namespace declarations consistent and unique
2. In your custom wizard create a new parameter which is passed into the templates, lets say `$customnamespace$`
3. Use `_preprocess.xml` to replace the namespace with `$customnamespace$`. That way you can keep your standard code so that you can F5/CTRL+F5 but the template version will have the namespace declaration replaced with this.

Then when your wizard is invoked pass the additional `$customnamespace$` parameter and it will be replaced. The multi project wizards do this, so the source may be helpful https://github.com/ligershark/template-builder/blob/master/src/TemplateBuilder/ChildWizard.cs.

More info on replacements https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki/How-replacements-work.

FYI we are looking to improve the docs so if you could contribute to [the wiki](https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki) that would be great.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Ill get right on it and try to follow your instructions. Ill update the wiki as it fits. Thanks

Comment: So i am having some issues with this approach. Mainly i want to change the ``Rootnamespace`` in the ``appname.csproj``, but that is explicitely excluded in the ``_preprocess.xml`` (``<Replacements Include="*.*" Exclude="*.vstemplate;*.csproj;*.fsproj;*.vbproj;*.jpg;*.png;*.ico;_preprocess.xml;_project.vstemplate.xml">``) and removing ``*.csproj`` from exclude will cause a build failure. Also this seems to disallow changing the Assembly name as well. Any insight @Sayed?

Comment: You should be able to remove *.csproj; from the exclude list. I've done that before. For example https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/blob/master/Project%20Templates/Azure/WebJobs/WebJobsHelloWorld/_preprocess.xml and C:\Data\mycode\side-waffle\Project Templates\Nancy.Csharp.EmptySelfHost\_preprocess.xml. Make sure that the thing that you are replacing is unique enough so that when the replacement happens nothing is incorrectly replaced.

Comment: I have tracked down what goes on. Since it will be a lengthy post i will make a new answer that explains the problems.